# Avoid deep routing in Rails yet still nest when needed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I've been deep nesting my resources and now discover that this should be avoided. Shallow nesting seems to be the answer but I'm struggling on how to properly correct the second level deep nesting. Let me show you my routes file as I think that will make it clearer(I'm using Rails 4):

OLD:

```
  resources :members do
    resources :emails
    resources :events do
      resources :items
    end
  end
```

NEW so far:

```
resources :members, shallow: true do
  resources :emails
  resources :events
end
```

My issue is I don't understand where to put the **:items** now? I thought it should be nested under the **:events** for the **:index, :new, and :create** actions?

What am I missing, I'm sure its something silly that I'm just not getting yet, please excuse my ignorance and I think you in advance for any help!!!

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is, update the routes as below:

```
  resources :members, shallow: true do
    resources :emails
    resources :events, shallow: true do
      resources :items
    end
  end
```

This will create shallow routes for `items`. Only for `:index`, `:new`, and `:create` actions you would get nested routes prefixed with `/events/:event_id`.

Comment: Thank-you for the help! That worked perfectly. I wrongly assumed having it so far down it would still look back up to the members. Thanks again for the help!